# How to create a custom field/facet for Search API?

Tags: 9, search

My Search API search page has a facet for Content Type, but I now want to add a custom entity in to the list of "content types" that users can filter on. I found some documentation on creating a "custom field" using a "custom processor". It was simple enough, during indexing, to add in values of either node bundle (content type) or the name of my custom entity. This does work; but, the facet block shows my content types in lower case. Even though the value I am adding with addValue() is mixed case, the value stored in the db is lower case. This makes me think I am doing something wrong. I have also stored the translated values for the content/entity type. Possibly also wrong?

Is it possible that I should only be storing the machine name of these types and I am missing something else that is used to display the values?

```
namespace Drupal\ssc_custom\Plugin\search_api\processor;

use Drupal\search_api\Datasource\DatasourceInterface;
use Drupal\search_api\Item\ItemInterface;
use Drupal\search_api\Processor\ProcessorPluginBase;
use Drupal\search_api\Processor\ProcessorProperty;

/**
 * Adds the item's URL to the indexed data.
 *
 * @SearchApiProcessor(
 *   id = "ssc_facet_type",
 *   label = @Translation("Facet type"),
 *   description = @Translation("Type to be used for facetted search."),
 *   stages = {
 *     "add_properties" = 0,
 *   },
 *   locked = true,
 *   hidden = true,
 * )
 */
class FacetType extends ProcessorPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getPropertyDefinitions(DatasourceInterface $datasource = NULL) {
    $properties = [];

    if (!$datasource) {
      $definition = [
        'label' => $this->t('Facet type'),
        'description' => $this->t('The facet type used for facetted search.'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'processor_id' => $this->getPluginId(),
      ];
      $properties['search_api_facet_type'] = new ProcessorProperty($definition);
    }

    return $properties;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function addFieldValues(ItemInterface $item) {
    $datasourceId = $item->getDatasourceId();

    $langcode = 'en';
    if (stristr($item->getId(), ':fr')) {
      $langcode = 'fr';
    }

    if ($datasourceId == 'entity:node') {
      /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
      $node = $item->getOriginalObject()->getValue();

      if ($langcode == 'fr') {
        $language_manager = \Drupal::languageManager();
        $language = $language_manager->getLanguage('fr');
        $original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
        $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);

        $type = $node->getType();
        $content_type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
          ->getStorage('node_type')
          ->load($type);
        $facet = $content_type->label();

        $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($original_language);
      }
      else {
        $facet = $node->type->entity->label();
      }
    }
    else {
      if ($langcode == 'en') {
        $facet = 'Policy instrument';
      }
      else {
        $facet = 'Instrument de politique';
      }
    }

    if ($facet) {
      $fields = $this->getFieldsHelper()
        ->filterForPropertyPath($item->getFields(), NULL, 'search_api_facet_type');
      foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $field->addValue($facet);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

EDIT:
After looking at this a bit more I am sure I should be storing the machine name as this is used in the url query to trigger the filter. If this is translated then switching from 1 language to the other loses the search filter query (not lost but remains in the original language and doesn't work in the selected language). This is also what the standard "Content type" facet does. It stored machine name in the db, uses it in the query but displays the translated label in the facet block. How?

Comment: I went back to storing the machine name in the db (when indexing content) and used a preprocess function to modify these to translated labels when displaying. Not sure if this is the best approach, but works well.